# Subnet group to the rds-NACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, subnet

If ec2 instance is spinned up in an subnet,subnet's NACl rules imply to the instances of that subnet,But where in case of rds, "subnet group" is attached to the rds instance. if I have 2 subnet's in subnet's group. In this scenario, which subnet's NACL rules are applied to the rds ?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch an RDS instance each instance will only be launched in a single subnet, the cluster on the overhand will spread instances across the subnets i.e. read replicas and Multi-AZ.

Each instance if you look at its properties will have availability zone, by using this you can limit down to the availability zone of the host. Assuming you only have a single subnet per AZ in your subnet group you can then identify the subnet.

If you have multiple subnets per AZ you would need to DIG (or ping) the RDS instances hostname to get the IP address. Then you would need to filter to determine which range it is in.